# How to Create Setup Project with Sqlserver Database Using Visual Studio 2008

Tags: .net, sql-server, visual-studio-2008, installation

I've tried to create regular setup project in .Net 2008 and it's working fine.

But the problem is the database.

I already have SqlServer database I want to attach database along with setup file.

When I start the installation it should attach the database on desired location.

Please help me on this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple: you do not. The setup project in Visual Studio is a degenerate simple case that does not cover more compelx scenarios.

Install WIX and write your installer the proper way - i.e. defining what you do.